# How can we integrate ESB(Enterprise Service Bus) with the Adobe AEM?

Tags: esb, aem, wcm

I want create a demo of an integration of ESB with the Adobe AEM. Even a very basic one will suffice. I need to understand if :
1. Is this is Possible/feasible?
2. How can one achieve this?

Please let me now if you have any questions.

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little broad.

What does "integration" mean in your context?

AEM ist built on Java Technology.
If your ESB provides a REST interface (or SOAP or RMI or JNI etc) you could access it in a component or a servlet etc.

You may want to look at this to get a clearer picture:
http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/cq/four-approaches-to-integrating-aem-with-external-systems/